# Running Lucee on Tomcat and need to server a JSP page

Tags: jsp, tomcat, coldfusion, railo, lucee

I have a Lucee box that is running with Tomcat.  Everything is great with the site and CFM pages.  I was recently given a page in JSP that the client would like to run on the site.  Everything I had read says no problem so I agreed to run it.

Put the file in a directory and instead of "processing" it ran like and html page would and I could see the code.  Realized that Tomcat hadn't been instructed to process JSP files so I added `<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>` to:

```
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CFMLServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.cfm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.cfml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.cfc</url-pattern>

        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>

        <!-- Basic SES Mappings -->
        <url-pattern>/index.cfc/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/index.cfm/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/index.cfml/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Now the page is blank and isn't outputting anything and it isn't throwing any errors.  Obviously "dump" doesn't work so I am not sure even where to start.

The beginning of the page is a series of import statements

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.rmi.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.*"%>
```

I assume that Lucee is "importing" them since I am not seeing an error of any kind but being that this is my first experience with JSP I am not sure.

I have written several things using java in cfml similar to

`Math = createObject("java","java.lang.Math");`

So I am sure I could eventually rewrite this in cfml if I have to but I feel like there is something small I am missing.

If anyone has any experience running JSPs like this you insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Ugh RTFM**

If anyone else runs into this.

Un-comment this section

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and this section

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

of /lucee/tomcat/conf/web.xml

Comment: So this seemed to work but today after a reboot we are back to the old situation where the jsp code is being displayed rather than being processed.  The above settings are still active in the web.xml but tomcat doesn't appear to be processing jsp.  All cfml file still working fine