# Function that includes JSP file is returning an empty result in Lucee but not ACF

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have a function utilizing an `include`, of a JSP file, to retrieve thread information which is then converted into a query object. The function returns an empty query Lucee, but it executes properly in ColdFusion.

*CFML:*

```
<cffunction name="mainThreads" output="false" returntype="query" access="public">
        <cfargument name="filterPages" type="boolean" required="true">

        <cfscript>
        var threadStackDump = "";
        var thread = 0;
        var stackTrace = "";
        request.threads = arraynew(1);
        GetPageContext().include("putParentThreadInRequestScope.jsp");

        ThreadQuery = QueryNew("id, name, group, stacktrace, alive", "Integer, VarChar, VarChar, VarChar, Bit");
        QueryAddRow(ThreadQuery, arrayLen(request.threads));

        for ( thread = 1; thread lte arrayLen(request.threads); thread = thread + 1 )
        {
            QuerySetCell(ThreadQuery, "id", request.threads[thread].getId(), thread);
            QuerySetCell(ThreadQuery, "name", request.threads[thread].getName(), thread);
            QuerySetCell(ThreadQuery, "group", request.threads[thread].getThreadGroup().getName(), thread);
            QuerySetCell(ThreadQuery, "alive", request.threads[thread].isAlive(), thread);

            threadStackDump = "";
            stackTrace = request.threads[thread].getStackTrace();
            for ( element = 1; element lte arrayLen(stackTrace); element = element + 1 )
                if ( arguments.filterPages )
                {
                    if ( findNoCase('runPage',stackTrace[element]) neq 0 or findNoCase('runFunction',stackTrace[element]) neq 0 )
                        threadStackDump = threadStackDump & stackTrace[element] & "#chr(13)#";
                }
                else
                    threadStackDump = threadStackDump & stackTrace[element] & "#chr(13)#";

            QuerySetCell(ThreadQuery, "stacktrace", threadStackDump, thread);
        }
        return ThreadQuery;
        </cfscript>
    </cffunction>
```

*JSP*

```
<%          
    ThreadGroup threadGroup = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
    Thread threadList[]=new Thread[Thread.activeCount()];   

    threadGroup.enumerate(threadList);
    request.setAttribute("threads", threadList);
%>
```

The code is not working in Lucee, but I'm not sure why. Does it have something to do with the java versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess you forgot to [enable handling of .jsp in your web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45974038/8895292), but ... you're not aware of it because the problem code executes inside a cffunction that suppresses all output!

Take a leaf out of Troubleshooting 101 and test the problem code in small chunks. Start by executing the JSP `include` separately. If it displays the JSP code on screen, instead of executing it, then you know JSP handling isn't enabled, and that's your problem.

```
<cfscript>
   GetPageContext().include("putParentThreadInRequestScope.jsp");
   writeDump( request );
</cfscript>
```

Comment: yea, you are right, it display the JSP code in browser, so just need to add ext in web.xml and restart Lucee

Comment: Yep. Not related to the issue, but ... you forgot to localize some of the variables with `var`.